# trying to subtract date from timedelta

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to calculate age of retirement date  if someone is going to retire at age 60.

```
import datetime as dt
DOB = dt.date(1984, 9, 6)
retire = DOB - dt.timedelta(365*60)
print(retire)
```

- Obviously,it can't subtract dates from days.

Comment: When I run the code, it prints me `1924-09-21`. How does this differ from your desired result?

Comment: I think you may want to add the `dt.timedelta(365*60)` to go forward 60 years from their birthday instead of subtracting the 60 years. I think it should look like this `retire = DOB + dt.timedelta(365*60)`. When you do that, it returns `2044-08-22`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify what unit you want timedelta to use such as days, hours, minutes. See the [datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

Your code also has a logic error as you are trying to subtract the amount of days from date of birth hence you get a date that is 60 years earlier than the date of birth. When you actually want a date in the future so adding the timedelta object is what you probably want to do.

Your code could look something like this:

```
import datetime

date_of_birth = datetime.date(1984, 9, 6)

retirement_age_in_days = 60 * 365

estimated_date_of_retirement = date_of_birth + datetime.timedelta(days= retirement_age_in_days)

print(estimated_date_of_retirement)
```

I would also encourage you to use spaces in your code, helps the readability a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime as dt

#Today date
today=dt.date.today()

#date of birth
date_of_birth = dt.date(1984, 9, 6)

#age retairing in days
retirement_age_in_days = 60 * 365

#Retirement date
date_of_retairement = date_of_birth+dt.timedelta(retirement_age_in_days)
print("\nDate of rtairement:")
print(date_of_retairement)

#Number days left
days_left = date_of_retairement-today
print("\nNumber of days left:")
print(days_left)
```

Comment: Thanks alot everyone,these really helped